# std array too few template arguments

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, console-application

When runnig my project i see these problems. Does anyone know the solution?
'std array': too few template arguments.
cannot use this indirection on type 'std::array'.
too few arguments for class template "std::array".
I tried to remove using namespace std; into std::array or cli::array but it didn't helped a lot

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "windows.h" 
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
using namespace System;
using namespace std;
class Dog
{
public:
  Dog();
  Dog(int initAge);
  ~Dog();
  int GetAge();
  void SetAge(int Age);
  void GawGaw(string S);
  private: int itsAge;
};

Dog::Dog() 
{ } 

Dog::Dog(int initAge) 
{ 
  itsAge = initAge;
} 

Dog::~Dog() 
{ }

int Dog::GetAge()
{ return itsAge;
}

void Dog::SetAge(int Age) 
{ itsAge = Age; 
} 

void Dog::GawGaw(string S) 
{ cout << S + " -> GawGaw \n"; 
} 

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args) 
{ 
  cout << "\n My Favorite dogs \n";

  Dog Bob;

  cout << "\nBob is a dog who is ";
  cout << Bob.GetAge() << " years old. \n";
  Bob.SetAge(7);
  cout << "No. Bob is a dog who is ";
  cout << Bob.GetAge() << " years old. \n";
  Bob.GawGaw("Bob");

  Dog* Fox = new Dog(10);

  cout << "\nFox is a dog who is ";
  cout << Fox->GetAge() << " years old. \n";
  Fox->SetAge(12);
  cout << "No. Fox is a dog who is ";
  cout << Fox->GetAge() << " years old. \n";
  Fox->GawGaw("Fox");

  Dog Rex(5);

  cout << "\nRex is a dog who is ";
  cout << Rex.GetAge() << " years old. \n";
  Rex.SetAge(8);
  cout << "No. Rex is a dog who is ";
  cout << Rex.GetAge() << " years old. \n";
  Rex.GawGaw("Rex");

  Console::ReadLine();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::array` has to be told the size at compile time.

Comment: @cigien Actually, since C++17, there's a [deduction guide for std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/deduction_guides) that allows it to deduce its type and size from the initializer.

Comment: This is C++/Cli. `array<System::String ^> ^args`. I assume deduction doesn't work there.

Comment: True, still needs compile time information though, and doesn't work for the OPs code. Command line arguments can't be known at compile time.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl deduction guide doesn't work with this: array<System::String ^> .

Comment: Remove `using namespace std;`. It's a bad habit that causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: @molbdnilo but what should I use intead? My program crushes even more than it has used to

Comment: Why did you add `array<System::String ^> ^args`? Do you need `args`?

Comment: @ThomasSablik should i delete it?

Comment: Remove `using namespace std;`, and add a `std::` in front of everything you want to use from `std`.

Comment: @DasElias didn't helped a lot, still the same problem

Comment: Have you also put a `std::` in front of `array`? If yes, remove this.

Comment: @DasElias Ok, i'll tru it

Comment: I don't know C++/Cli but in C++ you can remove it. `int main()` is valid there.